# Trigger task in AzureVM from local machine via command line

Tags: scheduled-tasks, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, windows-task-scheduler

What is the way to trigger a task that is in task manager of AzureVM from command prompt of my local machine??

I tried this (with AzureVm and task names)

```
schtasks /run /s <VMName> /tn <TaskName>
```

This gave me the error

```
ERROR: The network path was not found.
```

Both AzureVM and local machine are running windows server 2012 R2.

Answer (score 1):

To properly answer this question it will depend on what network connectivity exists between your local machine and the Azure VM. If you are connecting to the Azure VM over the internet then you need to either open a port for the VM on the load balancer, or you need to create a public IP address for the specific VM so that you can access all of the ports of the VM over the internet. Alternatively if you have a site to site or point to site connection to the VM then you can access the VM directly as you are doing.

Assuming that you are connecting to the VM over the internet, the easiest approach is going to be to create a public IP address for the VM, then connect to the VM using either the DNS name of the public IP address or just using the IP address directly. If you wanted to go through the load balancer then you would need to determine which port and protocol (UPD/TCP) schtasks is using so that you can open the correct port.

Also remember that the Windows Firewall on the VM may need to be updated to allow scheduled tasks to be executed remotely.

An alternate option is to use Remote PowerShell to execute the schtasks on the VM. Please see the following blog post that provides great overview on using remote powershell with Azure VMs: http://michaelwasham.com/windows-azure-powershell-reference-guide/introduction-remote-powershell-with-windows-azure/